# Split a string by word and detect/include line breaks

Tags: javascript, split

In order to animate headings word by word, I'm trying to split a string by space, but the CMS I use returns line breaks as `\n` inside of the string.

```js
const text = "Aenean non odio erat.\n Suspendisse vestibulum vulputate nulla et mollis."

const splitText = (text) => {
    const words = text.split(' ')
    return words
}

console.log(splitText(text))
```

Using this code, I get this result:

```
[
  "Aenean",
  "non",
  "odio",
  "erat.\n",
  ...
]
```

How to split the string by word but **keep including and visually show** (maybe with CSS using `white-space: wrap;` or `pre-wrap`) the line breaks?

Comment: Can you add your expected result too, please?

Comment: just split by `/\s+/`

Comment: @georg that works, thanks. Although, I would like to keep the line breaks as I want to control my text line breaks. `white-space: pre-wrap;` doesn't seem to help here as it's removed from the regex.

Comment: @flks: what is the ultimate goal? Why do you split the string in the first place?

Comment: @georg for animation purposes, show my headings word by word, I'm trying to avoid using a library for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to "normalize" whitespaces first, and then split by a space, so that newlines "stick" to the preceding word:

```js
const text = "Aenean non odio erat.\nSuspendisse vestibulum \n \n \n    vulputate\n\nnulla et mollis."

const splitText = text => text
  .replace(/\\n/g, '\n')
  .replace(/\s+/g, m => m.includes('\n') ? '\n ' : ' ')
  .trim()
  .split(' ');


console.log(splitText(text))
```

Comment: It is actually pretty good but I don't see the line breaks visually unfortunately, not sure why:
- render: https://pasteboard.co/JXKejSV.png
- inspector: https://pasteboard.co/JXKeO6W.png
- from the console: `(10) ["Aenean", "non", "odio", "erat.↵", "Suspendisse", "vestibulum↵", "vulputate↵", "nulla", "et", "mollis."]`

Comment: @fks: it might be a good idea to share your animation code

Comment: The animation doesn't really matter I think, it's more how the string is correctly split into words but including line break. I've made a REPL from Svelte (which is the framework I use): https://svelte.dev/repl/11699901bd5947e29d930da2dc7eb28b?version=3.37.0

Comment: @flks: look like your framework doesn't understand `\n` in tags, so you have to replace escaped newlines `\\n` with actual newlines `\n` in `splitText`, see above

Comment: Damn! I would have never figured that out. You're definitely a killer, thanks @georg 

Answer (score 0):

That is not the result, that I get. Your code should work properly. Did you post the whole code, or just a snippet of it?

Look:

```js
const text = "Aenean non odio erat.\n Suspendisse vestibulum vulputate nulla et mollis."

const splitText = (text) => {
    const words = text.split(' ')
    return words
}

console.log(splitText(text))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please first split by new line "\n" then split by the space " ".You got right answer.
Please refer this code snippet.

```
const text = "Aenean non odio erat.\n Suspendisse vestibulum vulputate nulla et mollis."

const splitText = (text) => {
            const words= text.split('\n').join("").split(' ');

            return words;
        }
 
console.log(splitText(text))
```